# How to get data from json array by python

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have following json object data, how can I using python to get both `"BuildId"` and second `"ftp"`  (note: it is within `"ArchiveLocation"`) value?

```
     {"BuildId":"4c53575f-36f48a7f1f37",
      "EventId":1,
      "ArchiveLocations":
      [
         {
            "archive_server":"CA",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC1.com/2011_V2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD\\dfs\\Department\\2011.4.103.002"
         },
         {
            "archive_server":"CT",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC2.com/2011_V2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD.com\\dfs\\Department\\2011.4.103.002"
         }
      ]

   }
```

Comment: {
      "BuildId":"4c53575f-36f48a7f1f37",
      "EventId":1,
      "ArchiveLocations":
      [
         {
            "archive_server":"CA",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC.com/2011_V2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD\\dfs\\Department\\2011.4.103.002"
         },
         {
            "archive_server":"CT",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC.com/2011_V2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD.com\\dfs\\Department\\2011.4.103.002"
         }
      ]
 
   }

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
data =   {
      "BuildId":"4c53575f-36f48a7f1f37",
      "EventId":1,
      "ArchiveLocations":
      [
         {
            "archive_server":"CA",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC1.com/2011_V2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD\\dfs\\Department\\2011.4.103.002"
         },
         {
            "archive_server":"CT",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC2.com/2011_V2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD.com\\dfs\\Department\\2011.4.103.002"
         }
      ]

   }

buildid = data['BuildId']
firstserver = data['ArchiveLocations'][0]['archive_server']
secondserver = data['ArchiveLocations'][1]['archive_server']

print buildid, secondserver
```

This returns `4c53575f-36f48a7f1f37 CT`

Alternately you can iterate over each key and pull the values that way. Its difficult to give you a complete answer because I don't know the context of your question.